# Spread function args in body

Tags: python

Possibly a dumb question but asking out of curiosity

In, python I can spread `*args` and `**kwargs` in a function's signature

```py
def my_func(foo, bar):
   print(f"foo={foo}, bar={bar}")

my_func(1, 2)          # 1 2
my_func(1, bar=2)      # 1 2
my_func(foo=1, bar=2)  # 1 2
```

Is it possible to spread it in the body of a function something like this?

```py
def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
   foo, bar = *args, **kwargs       <=== Something like this

   print(f"foo={foo}, bar={bar}")

my_func(1, 2)          # 1 2
my_func(1, bar=2)      # 1 2
my_func(foo=1, bar=2)  # 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`args` is a tuple, not `foo`.

`kwargs` is a `dict`, not the value of `bar`.

```
def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
   foo = args[0]  # Assumes there is at least one positional argument
   bar = kwargs['bar']  # Assumes there is a keyword argument named bar

   print(f"foo={foo}, bar={bar}")

my_func(1, bar=2)                   # 1 2
```

---

If you forgo using the signature, you have to be explicit about the mapping of positional arguments to names. For example,

```
def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) == 0 and `foo` not in kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Missing argument for 'foo'")
    else:
        try:
            foo = args[0]
        except IndexError:
            foo = kwargs['foo']

    if len(args) == 1 and `bar` not in kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Missing argument for 'bar'")
    else:
        try:
            bar = args[1]
        except IndexError:
            bar = kwargs['bar']

    ....
```

Here, I assume positional arguments should take precedence over keyword arguments. You could also make keyword arguments take precedence

```
def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) == 0 and `foo` not in kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Missing argument for 'foo'")
    else:
        try:
            foo = kwargs['foo'
        except IndexError:
            foo = args[0]

    if len(args) == 1 and `bar` not in kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Missing argument for 'bar'")
    else:
        try:
            bar = kwargs['bar']
        except IndexError:
            bar = args[1]

    ....
```

or continue to treat an attempt to use both as an error:

```
def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) == 0 and `foo` not in kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Missing argument for 'foo'")
    elif len(args) > 0 and `foo` in kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Multiple attempts to assign foo")
    else:
        try:
            foo = args[0]
        except IndexError:
            foo = kwargs['foo']

    if len(args) == 1 and `bar` not in kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Missing argument for 'bar'")
     elif len(args) > 1 and `bar` in kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Multiple attempts to assign bar")      
    else:
        try:
            bar = args[1]
        except IndexError:
            bar = kwargs['bar']

    ....
```

Comment: I'm aware args and kwargs are tuples and dicts respectively. In your solution, you're assuming `args[0]` and `kwargs['bar']` have values set. I want to break that assumption and be able to do `foo, bar = (), {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}` or `foo, bar = (1, 2), {}` or any other combination

Comment: Updated my question with possible function calls

Comment: If all you have are positional arguments, you are free to call either one by any name you want, *inside* the function. They aren't presented under any particular name, only by their position.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking now. `def my_func(foo, bar)` explicitly names the arguments. Using `*args` does not. `kwargs` doesn't name any arguments either, but at least each keyword argument comes with both a name and a value.

Comment: In the function's body, I'm trying to do what's done for you in the function's signiture. i.e assign arguments to variables correctly, regardless if they were passed in as positional args or named args or a mix of both. Im not sure how to explain it in a better way without the example I have in my question

Answer (score 0):

*args is just a tuple, and **kwargs is just a dict. You can use them like any other.

`for arg in args:`

`for name, arg in kwargs.items():`

Here is a guide on that:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3#:~:text=Understanding%20**kwargs,not%20enforced%20by%20the%20language.

Comment: Yup, I know what they are. I'm trying to see if its possible to map them to variables inline

Comment: Do you mean like `foo, bar = args, kwargs` ?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that by declaring the function with `(*args, **kwargs)`, there is no inherent ordering to `foo` and `bar` unless we later impose one in the body of the function.  But we could do something like this:

```
def my_func(*args, **kwargs):

    # we didn't say in the declaration what the arguments
    # were meant to be, but now we want to impose an
    # interpretation on the args,

    params = ["foo", "bar"]
    argsd = dict(zip(params, args))

    # and fold in the kwargs
    argsd.update(kwargs)

    # unpack into variables, choosing names based on the 
    # params that we are using (this rather assumes that 
    # the params list has been hard-coded because we wouldn't
    # want to try naming the local variables dynamically)

    foo, bar = [argsd[k] for k in params]
    print(f"foo={foo}, bar={bar}, args={args}, kwargs={kwargs}")


my_func(1, 2)  
my_func(1, bar=2)  
my_func(foo=1, bar=2)  
my_func(bar=2, foo=1)
```

Output:

```
foo=1, bar=2, args=(1, 2), kwargs={}
foo=1, bar=2, args=(1,), kwargs={'bar': 2}
foo=1, bar=2, args=(), kwargs={'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
foo=1, bar=2, args=(), kwargs={'bar': 2, 'foo': 1}
```